# Add to Linklist not working

Tags: orientdb

I have a linklist called 'Users' one of my table in orient db database.
I want add new item to Users.
When i execute following query it return with empty results with no error.

```
update #24:20 ADD Users = #12:1
```

Please advice me to add a new item to linklist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, which version are you using?

Comment: I tried your case with the latest version (2.2.13) and it works for me

Comment: i am using version  2.1.4

Comment: Try with the latest

Comment: I have installed version 2.2.1.3 . It works fine with new version. But query has changed to follows.

`update #24:20 SET Users = #12:1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed version 2.2.1.3 . It works fine with new version. But query has changed to follows.

```
update #24:20 SET Users = #12:1
```

thanks for the comments...